# Defining node style when label is different in each node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Is there a way to reduce the amount of TikZ-Code I have to write for this collowing graphic? Every node has the same parameteres except for the specific label text and its positioning so I thought of defining a general node style in the beginning. However, I am not sure how it works with the specific commands I need to use for my label placing.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

    \draw[dashed, color=cyan!50] (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \node[align=center, scale=1.5] (tmp) at (0,0) {Bildungs-\\standards};

    \node[circle, inner sep=1pt, draw=blue, fill=white, fill=orange] (A) at (1,0) {};
    \node[circle, inner sep=1pt, draw=blue, fill=white, fill=orange] (B) at ({cos(60)},{sin(60)}) {};
    \node[circle, inner sep=1pt, draw=blue, fill=white, fill=orange] (C) at ({cos(120)},{sin(120)}) {};
    \node[circle, inner sep=1pt, draw=blue, fill=white, fill=orange] (D) at ({cos(180)},{sin(180)}) {};
    \node[circle, inner sep=1pt, draw=blue, fill=white, fill=orange] (E) at ({cos(240)},{sin(240)}) {};
    \node[circle, inner sep=1pt, draw=blue, fill=white, fill=orange] (F) at ({cos(300)},{sin(300)}) {};
    \draw[blue!50!black!50] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(E)--(F)--(A);

    \node[label={[label distance=.1cm, align=left, rectangle, draw=blue!50!black!50, fill=blue!20]0: K1: Mathematisch\\ argumentieren}] (a) at (1,0) {};
    \node[label={[label distance=.1cm, align=left, rectangle, draw=blue!50!black!50, fill=blue!20]60: K2: Probleme\\ mathematisch l\"osen}] (b) at ({cos(60)},{sin(60)}) {};
    \node[label={[label distance=.1cm, align=left, rectangle, draw=blue!50!black!50, fill=blue!20]120: K3: Mathematisch\\ modellieren}] (c) at ({cos(120)},{sin(120)}) {};
    \node[label={[label distance=.1cm, align=left, rectangle, draw=blue!50!black!50, fill=blue!20]180: K4: Mathematische.\\ Darst. verwenden}] (d) at ({cos(180)},{sin(180)}) {};
    \node[label={[label distance=.1cm, align=left, rectangle, draw=blue!50!black!50, fill=blue!20]-120: K5: Mit symbolischen\\ Elementen umgehen}] (e) at ({cos(240)},{sin(240)}) {};
    \node[label={[label distance=.1cm, align=left, rectangle, draw=blue!50!black!50, fill=blue!20]-60: K6: Mathematisch\\kommunizieren}] (f) at ({cos(300)},{sin(300)}) {};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. The first step is to define styles for the nodes and for the labels, e.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,
    bullet/.style={circle, inner sep=1pt, draw=blue, fill=white, fill=orange},
    every label/.style={label distance=.1cm, align=left, rectangle, draw=blue!50!black!50, fill=blue!20}
    ]

    \draw[dashed, color=cyan!50] (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \node[align=center, scale=1.5] (tmp) at (0,0) {Bildungs-\\standards};

    \node[bullet,label={0:K1: Mathematisch\\ argumentieren}] (A) at (0:1) {};
    \node[bullet,label={60:K2: Probleme\\ mathematisch l\"osen}] (B) at (60:1) {};
    \node[bullet,label={120:K3: Mathematisch\\ modellieren}] (C) at (120:1) {};
    \node[bullet,label={180:K4: Mathematische.\\ Darst. verwenden}] (D) at (180:1) {};
    \node[bullet,label={240:K5: Mit symbolischen\\ Elementen umgehen}] (E) at (240:1) {};
    \node[bullet,label={300:K6: Mathematisch\\kommunizieren}] (F) at (300:1) {};
    \draw[blue!50!black!50] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(E)--(F)--(A);
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But you may simplify it further using a loop and a hexagon shape from the `shapes.geometric` library.

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,
    bullet/.style={circle, inner sep=1pt, draw=blue, fill=white, fill=orange},
    every label/.style={label distance=.1cm, align=left, rectangle, draw=blue!50!black!50, fill=blue!20}
    ]
   \draw[dashed, color=cyan!50] (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];       
   \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,draw=blue!50!black!50,
    minimum width=4cm,align=center, shape border uses incircle,
    shape border rotate=-60] (6gon){Bildungs-\\standards};
   \foreach \Text [count=\X] in {{Mathematisch\\ argumentieren},
   {Probleme\\ mathematisch l\"osen},
   {Mathematisch\\ modellieren},
   {Mathematische.\\ Darst.\ verwenden},
   {Mit symbolischen\\ Elementen umgehen},
   {Mathematisch\\kommunizieren}}
   {\node[bullet,label=-60+60*\X:K\X\space:\Text] at (6gon.corner \X) {};}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!